# C: What comes first -> or [i]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Say I have a pointer to a struct which has an array field called arr: p

Is `p->arr[i]` equal to:

1. `(p->arr)[i]` (which is what I was going for)

or

2. `p->(arr[i])` (which is an error)

Comment: [This *operator precedence* table might be of help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). And it will tell you that both operators have equal precedence.

Comment: if it's an error, the compiler will complain... no need to ask us.

Comment: `arr[i]` hardly has any meaning without the preceding `p->`

Comment: And Both, `(p->arr)[i]` and `p->(arr[i])` are same

Comment: *p->(arr[i])* kinda doesn't make sense.  This translates to *(p.operator->())->(arr[i])*.  *arr[i]* is the value of *arr* at index *i* (or *arr.operator[](i)*), which can't possibly be a member of whatever *p.operator->()* returns.  *p->(arr[i])* also doesn't compile.

Comment: (p->arr)[i] and p->(arr[i]) aren't the same at all... doesn't even compile. You can't tell what's arr[i] without using the struct type variable itself. Anyway, thank you all

Comment: and on that note.  what about ++p->arr[i]?  is this (++p)->arr[i] or (++(p->arr))[i] or ++(p->arr[i])?

Comment: @ethang ++p->arr[i] will be evaluated to ++((p->arr)[i]). Because, ++ has  lower precedence than -> and [] operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` operator has same precedence as `[]` operator. 
But it will be evaluated from left to right. So

```
p -> arr[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
(p -> arr)[i]
```

Comment: no, it hasn't; but they are evaluated left-to-right

Comment: some people simply don't read the already existing comments below the question... why-oh-why...

Comment: I don't understand why everyone talks about -> like it's a binary operator.  p->arr is not the same as p.operator->(arr).  It's the same as (p.operator->())->arr, so whatever follows p-> must be a token.  Parsing it any other way would cause a syntax error, so it can't possibly be p->(arr[i]), and this isn't due to order of precedence or direction of evaluation.

Comment: @ethang. There is no concept of p.operator->(arr) in C. It is an object oriented concept.

Comment: you're right, but internally, -> is not treated as a binary operator.  the thing on the right is not a value.  it's a token.  also, by your interpretation, ++p->arr[i] is  (++p)->arr[i]?

Comment: Obviously no. Because -> and [] has higher precedence than ++ operator.